# How DES/AES can guarantee by feeding different secret keys, the encrypted outputs are different?

Tags: aes, des, 3des

I am learning the meet-in-the-middle on DES attack. I understood the basic logic behind how it is performed; however, one further question is: why can we guarantee to find **one** and **only one** pair of k1 and k2?

One step further, how DES guarantee that by taking the same plaintext and different secret key, the encrypted outputs can never be the same?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. You are asking two completely different questions in one post. Please visit our [help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am learning the meet-in-the-middle on DES attack.

I don't know of any meet-in-the-middle attack on DES; I'll assume you're talking about 2DES (where you apply DES with one key $k_1$, and then apply another iteration of DES (possibly in decrypt mode) with another key $k_2$.

> why can we guarantee to find one and only one pair of k1 and k2?

We don't.  In fact, if we're just looking at a single plaintext/ciphertext block, there are likely to be circa $2^{48}$ $k_1, k_2$ pairs that map that plaintext block into that ciphertext block.

That is not a major obstacle; what we typically assume is that we have a second plaintext/ciphertext block that can be used for validation; given a candidate $k_1, k_2$ pair, we try those keys on our second plaintext block (and see if we get the second ciphertext block).  If it passes that, then it is most likely the correct $k_1, k_2$ pair.

This second check (which we may need to perform $2^{48}$ times) is less costly than the original MITM search, and so we mostly ignore that cost when estimating the cost of the attack.

> One step further, how DES guarantee that by taking the same plaintext and different secret key, the encrypted outputs can never be the same?

It doesn't; we generally assume that differing keys define different DES permutations (and so two different keys can map the same plaintext block into the same ciphertext block).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a followup question, can one-time-pad guarantees that taking the same plaintext and different secret key, the encrypted outputs can never be the same? I think so.

Comment: @lllllllllllll: About your additional question in the comment: The outputs are the same if and only if their (bitwise) xor is 0. Can you express this xor using the plaintext and both secret keys?